# Custom request and response type for express router

Tags: typescript, express

I want to create custom `express.Request` type that attaches logger to the request.

I don't want to override the original `express.Request` express instead create a new one that extends it, as some parts of the app have other middleware that attaches other custom properties to the request.

So in a `global.d.ts` I define the extended Request interface.

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { Logger } from "pino";

declare global {
  interface AppRequest extends Request {
    log: Logger;
  }
  interface AppResponse extends Response {}
  interface AppNextFunction extends NextFunction {}
}
```

Then in `some-app-router.ts`:

```
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();

function validateSecretMiddleWare(req: AppRequest, res: AppResponse, next: AppNextFunction):void {
  if (process.env.STATS_SECRET !== req.query.secret) {
    res.sendStatus(404);
    return;
  }

  next();
}

router.use(validateSecretMiddleWare);

export default router;
```

But I receive this error:

> Argument of type '(req: AppRequest, res: AppResponse, next: AppNextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
>     Type '(req: AppRequest, res: AppResponse, next: AppNextFunction) => void' is missing the following properties from type '(string | RegExp)[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.

I inspected `express.RouterHandler` and saw that it uses `express.RequestHandlerParams`, that uses `Request, Response, NextFunction` types, doesn't my `AppRequest` as valid `express.Request`?

Comment: I'm also looking for help on this question, I have a similar issue.